# Matriz en PHP y MySQL que permita contar por rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos con: `| codigo | Date | Hora |`,  pero quiero contar los códigos por semana.
Por el momento, lo que se me ocurre es hacer un QUERY que me extraiga todos los registros y con PHP hacer las condicionales, por ejemplo:

```
if($X['DATE'] >='2021-01-04' and $X['DATE'] <= '2021-01-10') { 
    $SEMANA[1] ='2021-01-04 &nbsp; to &nbsp; 2021-01-10';  
    $Contadores[1]+=1; $aux = 1;
} elseif($X['DATE'] >='2021-01-11' and $X['DATE'] <= '2021-01-17') { 
    $SEMANA[2] ='2021-01-11 &nbsp; to &nbsp; 2021-01-17';  
    $Contadores[2]+=1; $aux = 2;
} ...
```

Así hasta que termine el año, es algo tedioso porque cada año tendría que hacerlo igual.

Así ingreso la semanas y el contador por cada uno.

Comment: Agrupa por semana: `SELECT weekofyear(Date) semana, count(codigo) FROM tabla GROUP BY semana`.

Comment: Te agradesco mucho me ayudo crear la tabla que necesitaba:

Dejo el complemento para sacarlo por año:

SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(DATE) semana, DATE SemInicio, DATE_ADD(DATE, INTERVAL 6 DAY) SemFin,  COUNT(codigo) AS 'count' FROM  Tabla
WHERE DATE >='2021-01-03' AND DATE <='2022-12-31'
 GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(DATE)
 

Nuevamente se lo agradesco.